# Upgrading Cassandra 2.0.8 to 2.1.0

Tags: cassandra

I have 8 nodes in my cassandra cluster. Now I have upgraded cluster from cassandra 2.0.8 to release version of cassandra 2.1.0.

how can i upgrading cassandra to 2.1.0?

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Please review what have you written.... your question is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

First check your upgrade compatibility:
Cassandra upgrade for 2.1 version can be upgrade from cassandra-2.0.7 or later version.

Procedure:

1. Do nodetool drain on a single node
2. Take backup of cassandra.yaml file
3. Shutdown the node
4. For rpm install first uninstall dsc and cassandra rpm
5. Install new version of cassandra
6. Do all the change in new cassandra.yaml file as in old yaml file
7. If JMX security was enable earlier the do required changes in cassandra-env.sh file
8. Start the node with new version
9. Run nodetool upgradesstables on the node
10. Follow the same procedure on all nodes one by one

Before doing all that for your safe side you can take snashots first.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the documentation here:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeCassandra_g.html