# How to migrate from apache cassandra 2.0.3 to apache cassandra 3.11

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using **apache cassandra 2.0.3**. and like to upgrade to latest cassandra version. There are some docs present for cassandra 2.1.X to 3.x but not for **2.0.3 to 3.x**. I tried to search for a proper step by step doc for that, but could not find it. Could some one help me with this.

I also like to know whether the java driver will differ for both version. will there be any issue if i use same java driver. If so how to upgrade that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly upgrade from 2.0 to 3.x - you first need to upgrade to at least 2.1.9 (better to take latest 2.1.x), and after performing upgrade as described in the documentation, perform next step - upgrade to 3.x.

Regarding the Java driver - the latest version of Java driver should work with older versions of Cassandra, but the old version of driver may not work with new Cassandra (if you're using driver with version below 3.0, then it won't be compatible). See see [compatibility table](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/native_protocol/#compatibility-matrix) for full details.  See also [driver upgrade guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/upgrade_guide/) for concrete details about upgrading from older versions of driver.

Comment: where can i get documetation for migrating form 2.0 to 2.1 and then from 2.1 to 3. I searched documentation in datastax, it was removed. Is there any other documetation from migrations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012833/upgrading-cassandra-2-0-8-to-2-1-0, for example. But it looks like that you need to upgrade you 2.0.3 to latest 2.0.x first, because the answer in SO question mentions that upgrade to 2.1 is possible starting with 2.0.7